How to get Google to populate all the profiles from old computer?
Our profiles are stored in folders. Those looks like Profile 1, Profile 2, Profile 3, etc.
According to
Where are the user profile directories of Google Chrome located in?

Haven't seen this mentioned.
Profile folders on the system aren't named the same as the profiles in
chrome, the folders remain named as "default", "Profile1", etc.
In each directory is a Preferences file that can be opened in a text
editor. Search "name" (including the quotes) and it should be right
next to what that particular profile is named in Chrome.
Just another way to find which profile directory associates to which
chrome profile. Why chrome can't just rename the dirs....‍♀️

But that's just part of the puzzle. Surely there is a file or something where google sort of know how many profiles are there.
Something that looks like this

So there has to be some tables that list
Caesar, Michael, P, etc.
Where is that table? Which file contain that table?
Where does google store that info?
